# Android TextView text doesn't wrap properly according to maxWidth

Tags: android, variables, textview, width

In the image attached to this post I have made a green squiggly line to indicate space that is blank and doesn't seem to have a purpose.

I would like the colon separator to hug the actual text. In a perfect world, things look like they do for the "No Wrap" field shown at the bottom of the image provided. I am also okay with the "Another Wrapping Name" field, as at least the rectangle is being used up because of the word Name.

However, the "Field Name That Wraps" field has some obviously blank space between actual text and the edge of the `TextView`. The XML for the layout of each `ListView` item is included as well. You can see that the field names have no minimum width, but a maximum width of 128dp.

Here is my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/txvViewTextFieldFieldName"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:singleLine="false"
            android:textColor="#ff000000"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:maxWidth="128dp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/specialFieldNameSeparator"
            android:id="@+id/txvViewTextFieldFieldNameSeparator"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:textSize="22sp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:textColor="#ff000000" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/txvViewTextFieldFieldContent"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textColor="#ff000000"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The deafult Android TextView has some limitation in terms of wrapping text. If you notice you may already found that "**Field Names That wraps**" doesn't fits the TextView but "**Field Names Th wraps**" does. That's because the default TextView don't have the intelligence to recognize the scenario and change the text properties. Fortunatelly you can use a 3rd party library like,

[AutoFitTextView](https://github.com/grantland/android-autofittextview)

[image]

Which completely solves your current problem.